# In FAT12/16 on DOS and Windows, what extensions are used for directories?

Tags: windows, ms-dos, fat16

In a FAT entry, among other things, we have the extension field.

What values are commonly used in the extension fields for directories? Google fails me.

Comment: Can't recall for sure, but i remember having to leave extention 'fields' empty for restoring directories from tape in an old DOS/Netware enviroment about 8 or 9 years ago... I actually wrote a batch file for it i came across when clearing an old drive of mine last summer, had to strip out _'s and .'s too :)

Comment: @HaydnWVN Empty as in what? "_" or " " or something else?

Comment: Empty as in nothing/blanks! Michaels answer is very concise and accurate below! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall (it's been a really long time), in FAT directory entries, the file (or directory) name is stored as simply 11 sequential characters. What was traditionally thought of as the file name was put in the first eight bytes, and the suffix in the last three, right-padding to the length of each part of the file name field. This was sometimes rendered by stripping the padding and inserting a period in the middle, AKA `8.3`. Other tools (including plain old `DIR` without the `/W` flag) table-formatted the file names.

The [description of File Control Blocks (FCBs)](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2574.htm) in Ralph Brown's interrupt list says the file name and suffix are "blank-padded", which apparently means space (`\032`) (thanks [@afrazier](https://superuser.com/q/360293/53590) for the [link](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/fs/fat/fat-1.html#ss1.4)).

Comment: I know how that works. What I'm asking is what is actually in that last part of the name? Spaces?

Comment: See the edit. (filler)

Comment: Interesting! Not what I was hoping, since I can't use space, but informative none the less.

Comment: You should be able to use spaces just fine (as long as the software you're using supports them), just not at the ends. `ABC DEF.TXT` is probably fine, but `ABCDEF .TXT` likely won't work.

Comment: Also note that FCBs were deprecated fairly early on, but the constraints put on filenames by them (and the file system itself) remained.

Comment: The OS I'm using has some bugs, so at least one non-space is required in each past of the file name, which makes problems with directories (it only has support for root right now and I'm supposed to implement the rest).

Comment: If you are interested in the inner workings of MS-DOS and clones, then the RBIL is an invaluable resource.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, if you open a floppy disk in a disk editor, you should see that the extensions (and filenames for that matter) are padded with spaces because spaces were not supported in FAT12/16. You can also pad them with nulls since that has been used as both "blank/clear/empty/non-present data" and a string terminator since shortly after the big-bang. I have even seen FAT partitions with both (for example, look at the volume label entry in the root directory as well as the boot-sector).

Answer (score 3):

Typically?  Nothing. (Spaces)  Not that directories *can't* have extensions, it's just that most programs didn't use them.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Directory_table) and [this site](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/fs/fat/fat-1.html#ss1.4): directory entry names were padded with blanks.  Spaces.  ASCII 0x20 (32).

Comment: I mean, nothing as in what? What is that nothing? The room for the extension is there. What is stored in it?